# Recyclerview separates the data values,stores in one variable, and display values separately

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

**EDIT**

i changed my code and got a result but it breaks the data into separate values. it reads all the data from the database for each child. i have 2 childs but it only retrieves the last childs data and display its values separately. it stores its value from the variable `eta_text`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        clear_all = view.findViewById(R.id.clear_all)

        notificationView = view.findViewById(R.id.notificationList)

        notificationArray = arrayListOf()

        getNotifData()

        var linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        notificationView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        notificationView.setHasFixedSize(true)
 
    }


     private fun getNotifData() {
         val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
         val useremail = user!!.email

         dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
         dbref.child("Students").orderByChild("email").equalTo(useremail.toString()).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
             override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                 for (ds in snapshot.children) {
                     val idNumber: String? = ds.key

                     dbref.child("Notification").child(idNumber.toString()).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                         override fun onDataChange(dsnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                             for (dsd in dsnapshot.children) {
                                 val key: String? = dsd.key
                                 dbref.child("Notification").child(idNumber.toString()).child(key.toString()).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                                     override fun onDataChange(dsnap: DataSnapshot) {
                                         notificationArray.clear()
                                         if (dsnap.exists()){

                                             for (queueSnapshot in dsnap.children){

                                                 notificationArray.add(Notification(queueSnapshot.value.toString()))
                                             }

                                             notifadapter = MyAdapter_Notification(notificationArray)
                                             notificationView.adapter = notifadapter
                                         }
                                         
                                     }

                                     override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                                         TODO("Not yet implemented")
                                     }
                                 })
                             }
                         }

                         override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                             TODO("Not yet implemented")
                         }
                     })
                 }

             }

             override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                 TODO("Not yet implemented")
             }

         })
     }
```

My data class

```
package com.example.sqms

data class Notification(var eta_text : String ?= null,
                        var office_name : String ?= null,
                        var time_text : String ?= null)
```

My Adapter

```
class MyAdapter_Notification (private val notificationList : ArrayList<Notification>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter_Notification.MyViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val notificationView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.notification_view,parent,false)

        return MyViewHolder(notificationView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentItem = notificationList[position]

        holder.eta_text.text = currentItem.eta_text
        holder.office_name.text = currentItem.office_name
        holder.time_text.text = currentItem.time_text

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return notificationList.size
    }


    inner class MyViewHolder(notificationView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(notificationView){

        val eta_text : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eta_text)
        val office_name : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.office_name)
        val time_text : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text)


    }
}
```

picture below is the values from database
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka9lZ.png)

picture below is the data that is displayed separately
[notification recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEN2P.png)

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

i just solved it. i just removed the 3rd nested databasereference and changed the data writing

```
private fun getNotifData() {
         val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
         val useremail = user!!.email

         dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
         dbref.child("Students").orderByChild("email").equalTo(useremail.toString()).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
             override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                 for (ds in snapshot.children) {
                     val idNumber: String? = ds.key
                         dbref.child("Notification").child(idNumber.toString()).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                             override fun onDataChange(dsnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                 notificationArray.clear()
                                 if (dsnapshot.exists()){
                                     for (queueSnapshot in dsnapshot.children){
                                         val notif = queueSnapshot.getValue(Notification::class.java)
        
                                         if (notif != null) {
                                             notificationArray.add(notif)
                                         }
                                     }
                                     notifadapter = MyAdapter_Notification(notificationArray)
                                     notificationView.adapter = notifadapter
                                 }
                                 if (notifadapter.itemCount==0) { 
                                     notificationView.visibility = View.GONE;
                                     new_notif.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
                                 }
                                 else { 
                                     notificationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
                                     new_notif.visibility = View.GONE;
                                 }
                                 }
                             override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                                 TODO("Not yet implemented")
                             }
                         })
                 }
             }
             override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                 TODO("Not yet implemented")
             }
         })
     }
```